# Where is this Location in UK (somewhere in East Anglia perhaps?)

Tags: identify-this, england

[image]This painting was created by my late mother-in-law (Jeanne Girling), probably around 1980-1990's.

She often painted in and around her home town of Colchester but often travelled within East Anglia and I can only assume that it was in this part of England that she painted this building.

My wife doesn't know the location.

I have tried Google Image search but it only comes up with other people's artwork of buildings

If anyone has any thoughts I would appreciate it
Thanks
Paul

Comment: I would be quite surprised if someone was able to find where this is as the buildings are very generic and there are far too many water features in the area to use that as a starting point. But I've sometimes been amazed by what people are able to find...

Comment: Thanks.  I agree it is not obvious, though the double height large bay windows seem quite distinctive  Coupled with a bridge which appears to be the entrance driveway will hopefully give some folks a head start. I think though, as its probably 30-40 years ago, it may well have changed appearance by now.

Comment: I'm voting to close for the reasons discussed in these meta posts ([1](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6662/56885), [2](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6662/56885)) among others. In short: very little detail by which the place could be reasonably identified, and no relevance to anybody other than OP.